# what should be the steps to access s3 bucket with another region through lambda in aws cdk in python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created lambda in region A and a S3 bucket in region B , trying to access bucket from lambda boto-3 client but getting an error(access denied).how will apply policy statement and principal to access B region bucket. Please suggest steps in aws cdk.

Comment: What is your current lambda execution role? It needs permissions to read s3. Nothing else is required in terms cross-region access.

Comment: have tried but getting error access denied .do I need to add some bucket policy with some principal?

Comment: Usually you add S3 permissions to your function's [execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). Does bucket have existing policies?